# Regarding main method in java

Tags: java

In static method & static block, we can't use the instance variable & we can't create an object then how we use instance variable & create an object inside the main method, because of the main method is also a static method.

Comment: Who said you can't create an object inside main method? Just create it..

Comment: "In static method ... we can't create an object" <- No. That's just wrong. Of course you can create objects in static methods.

Comment: Please see how to supply a [minimum complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Your first assumption is correct while the second is wrong. You can create a new instance inside a static method.

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly access the non static instance variables in a static method. But you can create an object of the class in the static method and access both the static and non static instance variables of the object (which is a local variable inside that static method) in the static method.

```
public class MyClass {

    int i = 78;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        System.out.println("i is = " + c.i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create object inside main method and call to static method and variable you need
 classname.staticMethod().
Inside main write down 
classname instance _variable= new classname().

Answer (score 0):

The classes which contains satic method(s) usualy marked with final modifier. A final class is a class that can't be extended.

You can use static methods for Util classes where you do not need to handle stat just receive sone input data, do something with them and return the result. A good example can be the [Apache Commons Lang library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html). You can check the source code of the `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` class [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java).

You can instantiate any java object in a static method, example:

```
public final class StaticDemo {
    public static String echo(String text) {
        String response = new String("say ") + text; // for only demonstrating purpose
        return response;
    }
}
```

In a static method you can only use static class members:

```
public final class StaticDemo {
    private static final String SAY = "say"; 

    public static String echo(String text) {
        String response = SAY + text; // for only demonstrating purpose
        return response;
    }
}
```

Class variables hold the state of the object so it does not make any sense to use them from a static method which is belongs to the class.